# Drop duplicates with unique index : the new ones

Tags: mongodb

I'm droping duplicates using indexs:

```
db.things.ensureIndex({'source_references.key' : 1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

the problem is that it deletes the old documents (considered as duplicates ) and keep the new ones.
The old one are referenced in google so when someone clicks the link he gets 400 Error.
Is there any way to tell mongo to delete the duplicates that are new and keep the old guys in peace ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot tell mongo, which of the duplicates should be deleted. The better option in your case is to copy the collection record by record into a new one with `unique:true`. By chosing the right sort order while reading you can determin which of the duplicates are first (and by this are saved) and which are followers (and by this are deprecated).